# How to clear repeatedly set setInterval function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am using the below code to call a function recursively based on the condition. But once the setInterval is set, It is not clear and again and again the setInterval is set.
How to clear the repeatedly set setInterval function ?

```
function testFunction(ttlcount){

        jQuery.ajax({url:URL,
           type: "POST",
           data: { 'action_sub':'action'},
           success:function(res){

                            if(res < 0){ 
                                 if(interval != 'undefined'){
                                   clearInterval(setInterval); //clearinterval
                                 }
                                interval = setInterval(function(){testFunction(ttlcount)},1000); 

                              } else {
                                 clearInterval(interval);//clearinterval
                 //Do something ...   
                             }


        },error:function(e){

        }});
    }
```

Comment: why you don't just use setTimeout!

Comment: You should call clearInterval on the `interval`, not on `testFunction`. e.g. change clearInterval(testFunction); to clearInterval(interval);

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
setTimeout(callback function, timeout)
```

This will only run once, and if you need to run this single timer, then call it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(interval != 'undefined'){
  clearInterval(testFunction); //clearinterval
}
```

This should actually be:

```
if(interval !== undefined){
  clearInterval(interval); //clearinterval
}
```

When you call setInterval, you get a reference back to the actual set interval. That is the reference you need to pass to clearInterval to stop it, not the callback to be executed by setInterval.